# modifying code to be more specific?

Tags: python

My code removes consecutive duplicates in a string. What I want to do now is only have it remove specific duplicates. Example..

```
my_func("killkiss","l")
'kilkiss'
my_func("killkiss","s")
'killkis'
```

My code

```
def my_func(input,sub):
newString = ""
for char in input:
    if newString == "" or char != newString[len(newString)-1]: #I've tried adding 'and is sub'
        newString += char    
return newString
```

Is there a way to modify my code? I need the practice so no built ins from string library or imports.

Comment: Can you provide us with an example of a string you may have to parse?

Comment: When you call a function, you don't do `def my_func(input1, input2, ...)`, you simply call it, like such: `my_func(input1, input2, ...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for:

```
if newString == "" or char != newString[len(newString)-1] or char != sub:
```

Answer (score 2):

For consecutive duplicates, you can use [`replace`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) string method:

```
def my_func(input, sub):
    result = input.replace(sub*2, sub)
    if result == input:
        return result
    return my_func(result, sub)
```

Comment: The OP's code turns `aaa` into `a`.  Yours turns it into `aa`.

Comment: @DSM Thanks for pointing it out, now with a recursive call this case should be covered.